# Perl - If condition on regex captured groups

Tags: regex, perl

I have a log file and a regex that matches every line of the log file and captures groups. I want to print only those log lines which has `status = 404`.

This is what I was trying to do:

```
perl -ne '/(?<remote_addr>[-.\d]+) - (?<remote_user>[-.\d]+) \[(?<time_local>.*)\] "(?<request>.*)" (?<status>\d+) (?<body_bytes_send>\d+) (?<request_length>\d+) "(?<http_referer>.*)" "(?<http_user_agent>.*)" "(?<http_accept_encoding>.*)" "(?<http_x_forwarded_for>.*)" "(?<request_time>.*)" "(?<upstream_response_time>.*)" "(?<host>.*)"/  &&  print "$1\t$2\t$3\t$4\t$5\t$6\t$7\t$8\t$9\t$10\t$11\t$12\t$13\t$14\n" if ($5 == 404)' nginx.log > output/temp.log
```

But this doesn't seem to be printing anything.

My log line looks like this:

```
100.300.500.900 - - [23/Sep/2019:23:59:56 +0000] "POST /some/address HTTP/1.1" 200 1024 666 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows_NT ia32) node.js/4.4.0 v8/4.5.103.35" "-" "200.400.800.160" "10.30" "90.270" "www.mygoodserver.com"
```

If I remove the `if` condition it prints everything. So there can't be anything bad with my regex the problem has to be with `inliner if` condition.

Can anyone help? I'm new to Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has the form

```
/regex/ && print "some string\n" if ($5 == 404);
```

This is equivalent to

```
if ($5 == 404) {
    /regex/ && print "some string\n";
}
```

In other words, your code tries to use `$5` before running the regex that sets it.

In order to fix the logic, you need to use

```
if (/regex/ && $5 == 404) {
    print "some string\n";
}
```

Or in one line:

```
print "some string\n" if /regex/ && $5 == 404;
```

Alternatively, change the regex so it only matches lines where the status is 404:

```
/(?<remote_addr>[-.\d]+) - (?<remote_user>[-.\d]+) \[(?<time_local>.*)\] "(?<request>.*)" (?<status>404) (?<body_bytes_send>\d+) (?<request_length>\d+) "(?<http_referer>.*)" "(?<http_user_agent>.*)" "(?<http_accept_encoding>.*)" "(?<http_x_forwarded_for>.*)" "(?<request_time>.*)" "(?<upstream_response_time>.*)" "(?<host>.*)"/
```

Then you don't need a separate check.

Answer (score 1):

The statement modifier version of `if` is written after a command, but it's evaluated before it. Therefore, $5 has no value when you compare it to 404. Include the match in the condition so it happens at the right time:

```
print "...\n" if /.../ && $5 == 404;
```